# SQL сложный запрос "один ко многим"

Tags: mysql, sql

Ситуация.
Имеем 3 таблицы. Пользователь, доп. емейлы пользователя и некоторые данные, привязанные к каждому емейлу.

1. table_users

UserID | username | email

2. table_emails

UserID | additional_email

3. table_data

email | date_added | email_data

ЗАДАЧА:
username | email_data

Для каждого пользователя нужно вывести одни данные (email_data), первые по времени добавления (date_added). Причем данные могут быть привязаны к любому из емейлов пользователя, как к основному из таблицы table_users, так и к дополнительному емейлу из table_emails, которых может быть бесконечно много (реально, конечно 2-3 штуки). Данных email_data для каждого email может быть несколько, а может и совсем не найтись, так что как-то так: LEFT JOIN ..ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 1.
Все это в связке с рнр, так что думаю как-то динамически запрос строить, в первый шаг собрать в массив все емейлы, а потом типа:

```
<?php
foreach( $emails as $email ) {
    $i++;
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN table_data as td$i ON td$i.email = $email";
}
?>
```

Но как-то все равно не придумывается итоговый запрос... Помогите плз.

Запрос итоговый нужен единый. Мне нельзя разными запросами сначала выдернуть все данные по одному емейлу, потом если есть по дополнительному и тд и склеить на рнр. Потому что там все сложнее реально,  у всех таблиц есть еще поля и по ним надо осуществлять фильтрацию, сортировку и пагинацию.

Comment: Если есть 3 email у пользователя на выходе самые свежие данные для каждого из них или на пользователя строка только одна с самыми свежими данными по тому email для которого собственно они самые свежие. лучше привели бы примеры входных данных и пример выходных

Comment: Нужны свежие данные по ОДНОМУ из емейлов пользователя по дате добавления. Один пользователь-одни данные. Реальные данные - там вообще черт ногу сломит, полей с данными на самом деле несколько,  их тоже надо фильтровать, сортировать, вот и упрощаю как могу задачу. :)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю как то так:

```
select *
  from table_users U
  left join table_data D
    on (D.email, D.date_added)=
       (select email, date_added from table_data D1
         where D1.email in(select additional_email from table_emails E
                            where E.UserID=U.UserID
                           union all
                           select U.email
                          )
         order by date_added desc
         limit 1
       )
```

Если, конечно, у вас для одного email не может быть двух записей с повторяющимся временем (по структуре ваших таблиц это выходит так, ибо другого уникального ключа в table_data не прослеживается).

А вообще я бы предложил убрать поле email из таблицы пользователей и хранить все email в таблице emails. Если нужен "главный email" то помечать его специальным флагом в этой таблице.

Answer (score 1):

для конкретного user-a можно исрользовать подобный запрос

```
select u.userid, d.email, d.date_added, d.email_data
from table_users u
left join table_emails e on u.userid= e.userid
left join table_data d on d.email = e.additional_email or u.email = d.email
where u.userid = 1
order by d.date_added desc
limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b53b40/1

Comment: Какой из запросов более верный сложно сказать, но моя первая мысль была написать такой как у автора ответа. Он отрабатывает?

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы с сортировкой если информаци о основном email не вставляется в таблицу table_emails:

```
select
    u.username,
    COALESCE(td1.email_data, td2.email_data) as email_data
from users u
left join table_emails te on te.user_id = u.user_id
left join table_data td1 on td1.email = u.email
left join table_data td2 on td2.email = te.email
order by ???
```

Проблемы, потому, что время нужно выбирать то с "одной" таблицы, то с "другой" (td1 и td2). НО!!! Если вы в таблицу table_emails вставляете данные о основном email, тогда все в порядке:

```
select
    u.username,
    td.email_data
from users u
left join table_emails te on te.user_id = u.user_id
left join table_data td on td.email = te.email
order by
    td.date_add
```